# Running background process in LAMP stack

Tags: php, background-process, mariadb

I have an application running on **LAMP** stack.In USER model
after expiration of subscription deadline,I need to set user's current

subscription to default or free subscription.

So I need a background process which always checks for the expiration of user's subscription deadline and set to default subscription.

Is there any other efficient and manageable solution to run a background process which will update user's data ?

Application Environment:

> CakePHP,Redis,MariaDB

Please edit if this question isn't good enough to describe my problem :(

Comment: have you heard of http://gearman.org/?

Comment: @pregmatch, as far as I know, gearman can't schedule deferred events. Gearman is more like tasks solution, not events.

Comment: @ Ostrovski  when you create user just create gearman job that will execute on expiration subscription deadline. that is more cooler solution than creating crontabs and going to milion of records each day or minute or second. on he other hand you can always use atd daemon (http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl8_atd.htm). I am always using atd deamon (but that need some hacking becuase what if you turn of your server or your server dies or something like that)

Answer (score 0):

So in general your question about recurring event,
if this event do changes in DB and also another actions like send emails or stop some services or connect to remote resource,, you have to use cron job

but if this event only related to DB then you can create recurring event like [the following link](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/create-event/)

Comment: I have 200-500K users subscribed..so my event should check all the time for the expiration of subscription...so that event needs to keep running all the time on db. Is that efficient  for that much data?? @mohammad alabed

Comment: in my opinion, it is normal but you should improve this table and date column like using index (http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_index.asp)

Comment: mariadb events can be used in cluster too ??

Comment: honestly, I don't know, but i do not think so

Answer (score 0):

In case of PHP there is not so many out-of-the-box solutions. One of the available is [rabbitmq-delayed-sample](https://github.com/oscherler/rabbitmq-delayed-sample). It is built on top of [rabbitmq](https://www.rabbitmq.com/) messaging system.

Usage example:

```
$container->get('delayed_producer')->delayedPublish(5000, $messageBody, '');
```

where 5000 is an expiration period after that job will be executed. You can put such code to the new user creation place.